# Bootstrap JS popover take self content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap 3 "popover with image" to show bigger version on the hovered image.

I want the script to take as Content the image that has been hovered without targeting the ID=popover, so it will work on multiple different elements.

```
var Popover = function (element, options) {
    this.init('popover', element, options)
  }

  if (!$.fn.tooltip) throw new Error('Popover requires tooltip.js')

  Popover.VERSION  = '3.3.4'

  Popover.DEFAULTS = $.extend({}, $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.DEFAULTS, {
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'click',
    content: '',
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this...`data-image-url` in a div that you have the image.

here is the [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/akangjub/).

```
<div data-image-url="http://www.kiwibird.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/Five_Species_Of_Kiwi_Birds5.jpg" class="block1 show" rel="popover">Hover Me</div>  



<div data-image-url="http://mlbc.com.br/upload/blog/2014/12c92cf7aa5c8ee5a78f4eca149da8fe.jpg" class="block2 show" rel="popover">Hover Me</div>


$('.show').popover({
    'trigger':'hover',
    'html':true,
    'content':function(){
        return "<img src='"+$(this).data('imageUrl')+"'>";
    }
});
```